# How to stop hidden mac hidden files are showing in other systems?

Tags: linux, windows, mac-osx, mac

If i copy the Images or files from mac to other os systems, it shows the files `"._.DS_Store, .DS_Store"`  in other os systems.How to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe has [some notes and a unix command](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/remove-ds-store-files-mac.html) on this subject. It seems that it could be run before taking the image or after restoring it (providing the destination is a unix-like system).

> sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;

Comment: is there any option to restrict these files via samba while copying from mac to others?